# Mortal or Immortal soul?

Tags: death, soul

Before asking this question, I'll present this context: The underlying assumption for the previous arguments seems to be based upon the idea that man is only "bi-partite" (body and spirit). Yet, the NT clearly describes human beings as "tri-partite," "body, soul, and spirit" as stated in I Thessalonians 5:23. Job 32:8 states "But there is a spirit in man, and the inspiration of the Almighty giveth them understanding." However, because of Adam's original sin, spiritually passed down through the human genome, all human beings are born spiritually dead--death meaning separation from the life of God--not annihilation. In other words, mankind has no spiritual capacity to have a living relationship with God. The process of death--separation from God--would continue until the means of man's physical/material existence would cease--separation from physical life (Genesis 3:19). Death of both spirit and body is clearly evident in the Scriptures--one is material--separation from physical existence; the other, immaterial--separation from God--spiritual existence. However, the crucial issue at hand is what occurs with the "soul." It remains the other immaterial aspect of humanity. It appears that it reflects more of what we "are," rather than what we have (Genesis 2:7). The soul expresses itself via the body and is subject to death (Ezekiel 18:4). Both soul and spirit appear similar--yet each is distinct from one another (Hebrew 4:12). The question now is this: is the human soul "immortal?"

Comment: You make a false assumption within your reasoning, therefore your conclusion is in error.  We are not born spiritually dead, as the concept of original sin is man's idea, and not from God.  The children are innocent until the age of accountability when a mature choice will be required to either follow God's word, or to reject Him (Rom. 5:13; 7:9)  Would you then say that the innocent children are spiritually dead when God does not account sin to them?  If they die before the age of accountability, do their souls die too? I think you should rethink your question.

Comment: It would be interesting to see an answer that addresses this in connection with Ezek. 18:4 "**the soul that sinneth, it shall die.**" (KJV)

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. Questions on this site need to clearly focus on *one* specific passage. Questions asking for a synthesis of multiple passages are considered to be systematic theology questions and are off-topic here. They can be asked at [christianity.se] instead, but you'd need to specify which denomination's answers you are interested in.

Comment: This question (which should be divided into paragraphs that make it more readable and understandable) effectively answers itself. "*"body, soul, and spirit*" are the perishable physical body, its mortal life, and a spiritual component that provides intelligence and understanding (in the image of God). You quote Job 32:8 about the human spirit that distinguishes us from animals, and as pointed out in comments, Ezekiel 18:4 says that souls can die, so obviously they are mortal, not immortal.

Answer (score 1):

Mortal or Immortal soul?
Souls are mortal in two senses of the word.

First, Ezekiel 18:

> 4 Behold, all souls are mine; the soul of the father as well as the soul of the son is mine: the soul who sins shall **die**.

Second, Matthew 10:

> 28 do not fear those who **kill** [G615] the body but cannot kill the soul. Rather fear him who can **destroy** [G622] both soul and body in hell.

kill
ἀποκτεννόντων (apoktennontōn)
Verb - Present Participle Active - Genitive Masculine Plural
Strong's 615: To put to death, kill; fig: I abolish. From apo and kteino; to kill outright; figuratively, to destroy.

destroy
ἀπολέσαι (apolesai)
Verb - Aorist Infinitive Active
Strong's 622: From apo and the base of olethros; to destroy fully, literally or figuratively.

The resurrected soul can be terminated/annihilated in the Lake of Fire, Revelation 20:

> 14 Then Death and Hades were thrown into the lake of fire. This is the second death, the lake of fire.

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic theological questions.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that it was off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

A personality of a man, simply a person, who thinks, remembers, suffers (in an incorporeal sense), prays to and glorifies God and cares for his loved ones still in their bodily historical lives, - survives the physical death of this person.

That’s why Christians address the deceased saints that they may supplicate for the living for different needs; had the personalities of those saints been dead, what would be a point in addressing them? What is a point in addressing the emptiness?

Now, what should we call those persons, souls or spirits, is a moot point, given that Paul’s terminology is far from philosophical rigor and precision, such as we see, for instance, in Neoplatonic philosophers who very clearly and unequivocally distinguish between νους and ψυχή even though Neoplatonists fall short of the notion of person in its deep Christian sense.

The contention of heretics that soul co-dies with body, which will mean that resurrection is nothing but a re-creation of man according to God’s memory of him and his life, is a total ontological nonsense! Why? Here’s why: God can create only good things; He not only does not but cannot create either man’s evil condition (like, for example, his proneness to alcoholism and sexual debauchery) or evil memories, which rise pangs of conscience tormenting him. Thus, how then Hitler will be punished? For when God will create him anew (=resurrect him), this Hitler will have nothing to do with the one gassing millions of innocent people or shouting his paranoid speeches. God cannot create a sinner and then punish this creature of His: such a vision is not only stupid but outlandishly calumnious with respect of God.

So, what remains there: persons do not co-die with their bodies and resurrection is reunion of a living person with his resurrected body.

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic theological questions.

Comment: @curiousdannii ok. Yet, I do not quite see the off-topicality of the question, for it quotes Bible and the author bases his philosophical assumption on aspects of human essence on those quotes. Although those quotes aren’t, I’m my view, convincingly interpreted, still it is an act of hermeneutics and if so, then how can it be considered as off-topic?